# SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssms

In SSMS, I open Object Explorer to a (localdb) instance.  everything is good in ssms.  However, if I right-click on an object and select "Start Powershell", a new windows opens and after 30 sec or so I see the error messages:

> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to
>   'WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506'. [Failed to connect to server
>   WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506. --> A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)] At line:1 char:186
>   + ... WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506'']/Database[@Name=''RatesVision'']'|cd}
>   +                                                                       ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL...ses\RatesVision:SqlPath) [Set-Location],
>   GenericProviderEx    ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to
>   'WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506'. [Failed to connect to server
>   WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506. --> A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)] At line:1 char:186
>   + ... WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506'']/Database[@Name=''RatesVision'']'|cd}
>   +                                                                       ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL...44506\Databases:SqlPath) [Set-Location],
>   GenericProviderEx    ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to
>   'WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506'. [Failed to connect to server
>   WINL08160892\LOCALDB#3AD44506. --> A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)] At line:1 char:186

Do I need to do something special to start a powershell window from SSMS when running against a (localdb) instance?

Update: I see its not just (localdb) instances.  I have a similar problem connecting to another database server (that I am also connected to in SSMS):

> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to
>   'CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT'. [Failed to connect to server CRSDPRSCG1TBV.
>   --> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=29270;
>   handshake=26236;  --> The wait operation timed out] At line:1 char:138
>   + ...  'SqlServer' ;Convert-UrnToPath 'Server[@Name=''CRSDPRSCG1TBV'']'|cd}
>   +                                                                       ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT:SqlPath) [Set-Location],
>   GenericProvide    rException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to
>   'CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT'. [Failed to connect to server CRSDPRSCG1TBV.
>   --> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=29270;
>   handshake=26236;  --> The wait operation timed out] At line:1 char:138
>   + ...  'SqlServer' ;Convert-UrnToPath 'Server[@Name=''CRSDPRSCG1TBV'']'|cd}
>   +                                                                       ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT:SqlPath) [Set-Location],
>   GenericProvide    rException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to
>   'CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT'. [Failed to connect to server CRSDPRSCG1TBV.
>   --> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=29270;
>   handshake=26236;  --> The wait operation timed out] At line:1 char:138
>   + ...  'SqlServer' ;Convert-UrnToPath 'Server[@Name=''CRSDPRSCG1TBV'']'|cd}
>   +                                                                       ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT:SqlPath) [Set-Location],
>   GenericProvide    rException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to
>   'CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT'. [Failed to connect to server CRSDPRSCG1TBV.
>   --> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=29270;
>   handshake=26236;  --> The wait operation timed out] At line:1 char:138
>   + ...  'SqlServer' ;Convert-UrnToPath 'Server[@Name=''CRSDPRSCG1TBV'']'|cd}
>   +                                                                       ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT:SqlPath) [Set-Location],
>   GenericProvide    rException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : Cannot find path 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT' because
>   it does not exist. At line:1 char:138
>   + ...  'SqlServer' ;Convert-UrnToPath 'Server[@Name=''CRSDPRSCG1TBV'']'|cd}
>   +                                                                       ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT:String) [Set-Location],
>   ItemNotFou    ndException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

**Update:**
I can manually connect with

```
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\"CRSDPRSCG1TBV.3341"\DEFAULT
```

However, when connecting from SSMS, I would expect that the interface would automatically append the port in use.

Another type of failure from  PoSH is this:

```
> cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\"(localdb)\Vision"\DEFAULT
cd : Cannot find path 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\(localdb)\Vision\DEFAULT' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\"(localdb)\Vision"\DEFAULT
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\(localdb)\Vision\DEFAULT:String) [Set-Location], ItemNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand


PS C:\
> sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\Vision"
1> select @@servername
2> go

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WINL08160892\LOCALDB#823194D8                                                                                           

(1 rows affected)
1>
```

If sqlcmd can connect without issue, why does the Posh provider have difficulties?

Comment: I'm assuming that the [SqlServer](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer) PowerShell Module installed...? if you launch a PowerShell console, can you run the command manually:`Import-Module SqlServer; 
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\CRSDPRSCG1TBV\DEFAULT`

Comment: Correct about the install. Don't think I would have gotten this far otherwise.  Also from the error it looks like it's the CD that is failing.  Note that I'm launching from Ssms.  I expect it to just work. Otherwise what's the point of having the context menu action there?